# Server for sharing files and same Outlook everywere

Tags: linux, windows-7, outlook, file-sharing

i have plans to setup a server.
This must be for filesharing and getting the same mailbox everywere.
Because we going to have 2 locations for our business.
And i don't want to use usb sticks or dropbox

My situation:

Office 1:
This is the main office. With a very fast internet connection.

Office 2:
Here we have a normal internet connection.

The are 2 users, and about 4-5 pc's with windows 7 x64

What i would like to have:
To have the same mailbox everywere. Currently we are using Microsoft Outlook.
With large pst files. About 1,5 Gb per user.

And every access to all files. (varies from word/excel to photoshop and autocad)
And easy editing this.

Because i a new in the server world i don't know what i need.
Can this be done with a NAS? Or do i need a real server? Or a VPS (windows or linux based)?
Or just use VPN?

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance,
Ronny

Comment: It is generally advised against using *.pst files over the network. Please see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297019 for more info.

Comment: [And your objection to OWA would be, what...?](http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000519.htm)  Regardless, `.psts` are evil, and should be purged from the world with nuclear fire... or a properly configured server and the delete key, which ever is easiest for you.

Comment: For mails there is another option is IMAP it will be sync and have same folder structures at both location. Even Sent emails would be synced.